# What is the implication of memset() for va_list?

Tags: c, memset, variadic-functions

I read the following code fragment:

```
va_list args;
memset(&args, 0, sizeof(va_list));

va_start(args, xxx);
...
va_end(args);
```

What is the implication of `memset()` here directly before `va_start()`?

What is the difference if the `memset()` line is removed?

Comment: It fills the `args` variable with zeros.

Comment: Where did you find this code? I think that is useless since `va_start` write in `args` after.

Comment: Interesting.  `va_start(args, xxx);` does not _look_ like is initializes `args` any more than `foo(args)` would not be expected to affect `main()`'s `args`.  Yet `va_start` is a macro and does affect `args`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The implication is that the programmer who wrote this does not know what they are doing, and enjoys wasting code.

They may be blindly following the directive of some static analysis tool that variables must be initialized before they are used.

`va_start(args, xxx);` does all the necessary initialization, and overwrites all the 0-values that `memset` just put in, making the work of `memset` worthless.

Answer (score -1):

`memset` sets the memory bytewise. It does not care what the type of the arguments are, in fact, it takes a `void` pointer.

It will set `count` no of memory locations after `dest` to the character `ch`

```
void* memset( void* dest, int ch, size_t count )
```